# Installed Bitcoin-QT on windows2008r2 server, but it won't snyc anything at all

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, server, installation

Installed Bitcoin-QT on windows2008r2 server, but it won't sync anything at all. No connections to network, no blocks, no movement full stop. I have OK'd it in windows firewall, tried connecting through the socks proxy option / turned socks off - no dice - added nodes in bitcoin.conf file etc. Everything I can think of, I have no doubt its probably a server issue - but I still have no idea what to do! It's just doing literally nothing - any ideas? I set TCP and UDP rules, which were auto created in firewall, to allow all ports to the client.

It says, in the client:-

No connections to the network available. Catching up, processed 0 of 250000.

Thx in advance.

Comment: I think this should be better placed over at Server fault. Probably not related to Bitcoin.

Comment: Please paste the full contents of your bitcoin.conf file. 

Also why don't you try hitting up the fallback nodes: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fallback_Nodes